# BroadcastReceiver independent from app process

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi, android-lifecycle

There is a state of my app in which it does nothing but scanning wifi (actually wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers). In that state it should use minimal energy but react quickly on broadcast intents.

1) Am I right that the receiver object is created before registering programmatically and keeps loaded until unregistered as long as the app's process is not killed?

2) How can I prevent the process from being killed without wakelocks which would also harm power consumption?

3) Can CPU be stopped while wifi scanning, i.e. while WifiLock is acquired?

4) How can a WifiLock can be held when a process is killed ->2?

5) Can I register a BroadcastReceiver class which will be created just when there is an intent to handle even when the app's process was killed?

Hope this is understandable. Maybe the following outline helps a bit:

```
Boot or app start
loop
    initiate wifi scan
    loop
        sleep (stop CPU and release memory if possible)
        process scan event (potentially calling services and activities)
    until scan complete
forever
```

Currently I have the feeling that I need a service in parallel to the receiver to hold reference of the receiver and keep this service running all the time, but at least without wakelocks. Is this right? Or is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: 1) I have no idea what this sentence means. 2) You can't, and a `WakeLock` does not affect the process lifetime anyway (e.g., "from being killed") 3) Yes, if there is no `WakeLock` 4) AFAIK, it can't 5) Register it in the manifest via a `<register>` element (though whether this is possible for the specific unnamed broadcast you are trying to use, I can't say).

Comment: Thx for the answer. ad 5) IMO I can't register in manifest as this receiver as  discoverPeers is just a temporary action, and also should only happen under certain conditions. I trigger it via activity and by BootCompletedReceiver. So when registered programmatically by a process which is killed later then the receiver object is unregistered and gone too, right? Is there a way to have the system create a new receiver object in case a matching broadcast?

Comment: This would avoid the need to have a permanent service just to maintain reference to the receiver object.

Comment: "discoverPeers is just a temporary action, and also should only happen under certain conditions" -- that does not mean that the `BroadcastReceiver` has to be registered via `registerReceiver()`. It can still be in the manifest. "So when registered programmatically by a process which is killed later then the receiver object is unregistered and gone too, right?" -- correct. "Is there a way to have the system create a new receiver object in case a matching broadcast?" -- register it via the manifest, instead of via `registerReceiver()`.